# How to add wildcard to Heroku app without custom domain?

Tags: heroku, wildcard

I tried to add wildcard domain to my existing app hosting as mysite.herokuapp.com - **without** a custom domain. The point is it's my test app and application itself allows end users create apps that would be visible as subdomains.

So I configured custom domain and wildcard for main prod app, now I want it to be done for my dev (test) app - so here I need *only wildcard* but not custom domain. If I try to do it I have "Can't add an additional Heroku domain." What to do to fix it? Is it even possible? Thanks!

UPDATE I have the official answer from Heroku support. It's impossible, I can only add wildcard domain to my custom domain.